# Spark exception when inserting dataframe results into a hive table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is my code snippet. I am getting following exception when `spar.sql(query)` is getting executed.

My `table_v2` has `262 columns`. My `table_v3` has `9 columns`.

Can someone faced similar issue and help to resolve this? TIA

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
sc=spark.sparkContext

df1 = spark.sql("select * from myDB.table_v2")
df2 = spark.sql("select * from myDB.table_v3")

result_df = df1.join(df2, (df1.id_c == df2.id_c) & (df1.cycle_r == df2.cycle_r) & (df1.consumer_r == df2.consumer_r))
final_result_df = result_df.select(df1["*"])

final_result_df.distinct().createOrReplaceTempView("results")
query = "INSERT INTO TABLE myDB.table_v2_final select * from results"
spark.sql(query);
```

I tried to set the parameter in conf and it did not help to resolve the issue:

```
spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields=500
```

Error:

```
20/12/16 19:28:20 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Job job_20201216192707_0002 aborted.
20/12/16 19:28:20 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 90.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 225)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing required char ':' at 'struct<>
    at org.apache.orc.TypeDescription.requireChar(TypeDescription.java:293)
    at org.apache.orc.TypeDescription.parseStruct(TypeDescription.java:326)
    at org.apache.orc.TypeDescription.parseType(TypeDescription.java:385)
    at org.apache.orc.TypeDescription.fromString(TypeDescription.java:406)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcSerializer.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$orc$OrcSerializer$$createOrcValue(OrcSerializer.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcSerializer.<init>(OrcSerializer.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcOutputWriter.<init>(OrcOutputWriter.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(OrcFileFormat.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.newOutputWriter(FileFormatWriter.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:378)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1415)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have dropped my `myDB.table_v2_final` and modified the below line in my code and it worked.

I suspect there might be some issue in the way I created the table.

```
query = "create external table myDB.table_v2_final as select * from results"
```